# Wordpress Archive by Year "query_posts()" Problem

Tags: wordpress, archive

I created an [Archive list](http://boltart.fatihturan.com/arsiv/) ([also this is my archive.php codes](http://www.pastie.org/private/woml3fhydj2qkh4resfhg)) on my blog and i want to show posts by years.

But when i use `query_posts()` function for excluding some categories and limit posts then it's showing all posts not by year.

For example [this page](http://boltart.fatihturan.com/2009/) is showing all posts not only posts in 2009 years.

So if i summarize this issue; i want to show archive list by year (when i enter /2009/ permalink)+exclude some categories and limit posts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe when you use global variable, $query_string, it will help.

so you must use it like this

```
global $query_string;
query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-13,-4,-14,-171&posts_per_page=5&paged='. $paged);
```

as codex mention, here :  [query post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts),

> Place a call to query_posts() in one of your Template  files before The Loop begins. The wp_query object will generate a new SQL query using your parameters. When you do this, WordPress ignores the other parameters it receives via the URL (such as page number or category). If you want to preserve that information, you can use the $query_string  global variable in the call to query_posts().

Comment: Thanks. It's working but there are new problem with pagination. If i click previous post link (Önceki Sayfa -> (http://snipurl.com/uwvyo)) on this page (http://snipurl.com/uwvxv) then it's returning error 404 page. This is my new archive.php codes (http://www.pastie.org/private/0ddd1n4nxhoouguq3ahdfg). How i can fix this issue?

Comment: what happen if you use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query | wp_reset_query(), after the loop and before a pagination...

Comment: Thanks you sir. It's worked. I want to ask new question about this topic; query_posts() function is not excluding some categories (i.e: category id=13). Latest archive.php codes is here: http://bit.ly/bjYljq Why so? I can't understand.

Comment: how about you use '&' between $query_post and the cat=-13, -4,.. as i wrote in comment section. if this not work, please tell, i will try to figure it out after i'm back to the office

query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-13,-4,-14,-171&posts_per_page=5&paged='. $paged);